# Unable to build iOS or Android app after upgrade to Flutter 3.0

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

After upgrading to Flutter 3.0 I am no longer able to build any of my apps for either iOS or Android and get the same errors in both builds:

```
: Error: Member not found: 'UnicodeChar'.
  int get UnicodeChar => Char.UnicodeChar;
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: Setter not found: 'UnicodeChar'.
  set UnicodeChar(int value) => Char.UnicodeChar = value;

                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: Member not found: 'AsciiChar'.
  int get AsciiChar => Char.AsciiChar;
                            ^^^^^^^^^
: Error: Setter not found: 'AsciiChar'.
  set AsciiChar(int value) => Char.AsciiChar = value;

                                   ^^^^^^^^^
```

and these errors are in the file "src/structs.g.dart" (part of Flutter/Dart as far as I can tell) as follows:

```
/// {@category Struct}
class _CHAR_INFO__Char_e__Union extends Union {
  @Uint16()
  external int UnicodeChar;
  @Uint8()
  external int AsciiChar;
}

extension CHAR_INFO_Extension on CHAR_INFO {
  int get UnicodeChar => Char.UnicodeChar;
  set UnicodeChar(int value) => Char.UnicodeChar = value;

  int get AsciiChar => Char.AsciiChar;
  set AsciiChar(int value) => Char.AsciiChar = value;
}
```

I am running VSCode 1.67.1 on macOS Monterey 12.3.1 and
`flutter doctor -v` shows no errors found.

It appears that the file "src/structs.g.dart" seems to be part of the Win32 components in "pub.dartlang.org" but I am not building my apps for Windows (yet).

Any ideas on what I need to do to be able to build for iOS and Android again will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Les

Answer (score 3):

So, something which helped me:

1. remove the next folder `/Users/your-user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org`
2. hit `flutter pub upgrade`

and then try to run your project

Comment: Hi Andriy,
On its own that did not work but after then running `flutter pub upgrade` it is now all good.
Many thanks.

Comment: Awesome :)
 glad to help. please if you don't mind - accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

Steps to solve your problem:

1. First Of all, You Need To Update all Third-party Packages

   flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
2. Now You need to clean your project

   flutter clean
3. Delete "pubspec.lock" file at the root of your project (manually or run the script)

   rm -rf pubspec.lock
4. Now, You need to Get all Packages

   flutter pub get

Now you can run your project and the error should be solved ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. Step 1: Delete pod folder in ios.
2. Step 2: uncomment the code at the line # platform :ios, '9.0' in
   Podfile.
3. Step 3: change line platform :ios, '9.0' to  platform :ios, '10.0'
4. Step 4: run : `flutter pub upgrade`
5. Step 5: cd ios , run `pod install`
6. Step 6: run `pod repo update` and `sudo gem install cocoapods` and run again `pod repo update` and run `pod install`

   Step 7: run again project . goodluck

Comment: Flow step below :

Answer (score 0):

Delete the build folder, run flutter clean. I had the same problem with a macOS project and had to delete the macOs folder. Works fine afterwards.

Comment: I deleted the build folder and ran flutter clean but it made no difference (I am still getting the same errors)...

Comment: same here.. errors persist... and Flutter doctor show Visual Studio Error - Exception: Bad UTF-8 encoding (U+FFFD; REPLACEMENT CHARACTER) found while decoding string

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade flutter to the previous version "flutter downgrade" until an upgrade to flutter 3.0.0 is provided by the owners of all packages you are using in your project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).